# VBA Word - insert a cross reference to a bookmark, but keep the style of the context

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Word I have a list of *Bookmarks* and want to insert cross references (copy the text and have a hyperlink) to those bookmarks. With macro recording and adjusting parameters I got this which replaces `myRange` with the text of `myBookmark` and makes a hyperlink to that bookmark:

```
myRange.InsertCrossReference _
    ReferenceType:=wdRefTypeBookmark, _
    ReferenceKind:=wdContentText, _
    ReferenceItem:=myBookmark, _
    InsertAsHyperlink:=True
```

This works fine except for one thing: if I change the style of the text I bookmarked (e.g. make it bold) and update the cross references then the cross references also adopt that style - I'd need to copy *only* the text in the bookmark, but the style (color, boldness, whatever) should remain the one from the context where the cross reference is (e.g. text should stay italic or blue or whatever).

Changing the style of the cross reference manually isn't of much help - after updating the cross reference field, the style falls back to the one of the bookmark.

I can't believe that there's no option for this, and I don't even see how to get that kind of bookmark/cross reference manually (without VBA). Any hints?

Note: when I do a `ClearFormatting` to the range before I bookmark it (and set that style back afterwards), then cross references will keep their style even after updating the field (so far so good), unless (sic!) they don't have a style, then they will adopt the changed style of the bookmark - if the bookmark is in plain text, this isn't a problem, but if it is in - say - a table with italic words, I'll adopt this italic format for all cross references that don't have a style yet. So, what's a general solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use the * CharFormat switch in the REF field code underlying the cross-reference.

Example cross-reference to the bookmark "test":

```
REF test \h \* CharFormat
```

You can see the field code by toggling the view using Alt+F9. Test by adding the switch, then pressing F9 to force the field update.

There's no option for adding this switch in the object model. But you can do it fairly easily by editing the Field.Code.Text property. Example

```
ActiveDocument.Fields(2).Code.Text = _
     ActiveDocument.Fields(2).Code.Text & " \* CharFormat "
```

Comment: You plan to become my VBA hero, right? Everythings working fine now. One thing I don't understand yet: after I `myRange.InsertCrossReference` there should be a `Field` in `myRange`, but Word doesn't see it unless I extend the range by `myRange.End = myRange.End + 1`. And an additional note: after I add `myRange.Fields(1).Code.Text = myRange.Fields(1).Code.Text & " \* CharFormat "` I have to manually `myRange.Fields(1).Update` as the `\* CharFormat ` wasn't active yet when I did the `myRange.InsertCrossReference`. Many thanks for your valuable help.

Comment: Sidenote: it seems that `Fields` can't have mixed formatting - after updating the `Field` the formatting is the one of the first character - but I guess that's a general problem in Word - and I can live with that

Comment: And another sidenote: you may have to use `Selection.CopyFormat` and `Selection.PasteFormat` in case the formatting of the text to be cross referenced begins with the new formatting - inserting the cross reference seems to insert a new run adopting the _Format_ of the text before (Cindy, correct me if I'm wrong :-))

Comment: 1) Sometimes, Word extends the Range or returns a Range when you insert, other times not. This is one of those "other times". Whether it does, or not, is sometimes in the Help of the method, but often testing is the only way to find out.

Comment: 2) Yes, you need to update the field in order to see the effect of changes to the field code.

Comment: 3) If you use the \* MergeFormat switch a field can return mixed formatting but there's an important caveat: The field stores the original formatting as applied *per character*. This is fine, until the Result changes. At that point, the formatting can get really screwed up. So the only time I use MergeFormat is when I'm linking in tables from Excel. (And yes, CharFormat picks up the formatting of the first character of the field.)

Comment: This fixed my issue in Offce:Mac. There is no context menu option to preserve formatting, so I just insert the bookmark, then manually add `\* CharFormat`.